# WPF DataGrid: How to determine the index of the row in which a ComboBox selection changed?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, combobox

I have been using this code, in order to determine the current row being **edited interactively**:

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyModel myModel = (MyModel) dataGrid.CurrentItem;
    int rowIndex = dataGrid.Items.IndexOf(myModel);
    [...]
}
```

The limitation of this approach is that the event handler is also executed when the ComboBox selection changes **programmatically**. In that case, `CurrentItem` is null and thus I don't know the row index.

TIA

Note: I do not really need the row index per se, I could use the Model (`CurrentItem`) as well.

Edited after I solved the problem: Notice how the code above ignores the arguments (which tend to contain really **important** stuff!!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I was looking for...

```
private void ComboBoxRight_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox comboBox    = (ComboBox) sender;
    DataGridRow row      = (DataGridRow) dataGrid.ContainerFromElement(comboBox);
    int rowIndex         = row.GetIndex();
    MyModel gridModel    = (MyModel) dataGrid.Items[rowIndex];
}
```

-Travis

Answer (score 0):

You can use dateGrid.Selected index to find whether value is set from UI or code behind

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if(dataGrid.Selected>=0)
   {
     MyModel myModel = (MyModel) dataGrid.CurrentItem;
     int rowIndex = dataGrid.Items.IndexOf(myModel);
      [...]
     dataGrid.Selected=-1;
   }

}
```

In the above case even thought comobox selection changed called when the value is changed from code behind, dataGrid selected index will be -1. But when the user changes it from the Ui you'll get the selected index of particular row and again it'll set to -1.